# Loopback Rest API without connecting to database

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am planning to use some service from other SDK, but I don't know how to create a Rest API without having to connect to datasource. Currently, I have to create a remote hook inside a loopback database model which are not even relevant to each other. For example, I would like to call a Text Message Service API from Twilio, but I have to create the remote hook in Class Model since it's connected the database. Can I create a API without creating a model and connected to the datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using 3rd party REST APIs you can use a [loopback-connector-rest](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest) datasource. The documentation for the connector can be found [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/REST+connector).

Otherwise, you can create a model without connecting it to a datasource by setting it up in your `model-config.json` as follows:

```
"ModelName": {
  "datasource": null
}
```